# Oracle database driver benchmark

Tags: oracle, scala, jvm, driver

I'm actually working in a situation where a .NET stack is managing an Oracle Database. Now, because the legacy code is consistently based on PL SQL stored procedures that deal with the majority of the work, the correct choice of driver to connect to the database is of primary importance.

For this reason, knowing that Oracle provides a large number of driver for the most known programming languages, I was trying to find a **documented benchmark** (even with all the problem and the influence of the context in which the tests are made) that **could compare the different Oracle drivers for the different programming languages**, just to support the hypothesis that **the best choice in terms of performance** for an isolated test microservice **would be to use the Java driver in combination with Scala** (Java is now property of Oracle now, after all).

Are there any on the internet that could support (or not) this hypothesis?

**EDIT**

I didn’t provide all the information. What I’m trying to achieve is develop a series of microservices focused on fetching data from the database and convert them into json to be consumed by the front end. .NET driver behaves seamlessly until the numbers become really overwhelming (> 1000 rows).

That’s why I was wondering if it could make any sense using JDBC to increase performance, having heard that, for instance, .NET driver for SQL server, both made by the same Company, performs 5 times better than the oracle one when it comes to gathering data from a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice of drives may not give you the milage if most of the work is in PL/SQL or stored procedures. Having said that, jdbc is a good choice. However do not fight if developers are more familiar with other drivers like Oracle ODBC, oracle provider for .NET, ADO,etc.. all protocols have a Oracle drive to access Oracle DB.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You’re right about the stored provedores and the habits of the developers, but what I’m trying to accomplish is a little service capable of fetch data from the database and convert it in json for the front end in the most critical situations, where .NET  could take minutes to process all data, that’s why I was wondering if there would be a performance improvement using JDBC instead of .NET driver.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have to convert to json. Oracle DB can convert it. Your network latency is more impacted by how big the pipe is ,array size,and packet size than protocols.